# searchable autocomplete using google map api menu in android

Tags: android, dictionary, autocomplete, searchview

I followed  [this tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/)    for doing the searchView ActionBar but I want  autocomplete textview using google places api in this searchable  by the place names as we start typing..Can someone suggest an example  or a way out?

Answer (score 1):

hope [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) will help you.
Happy Coding.

Comment: thanks but I want to seach and  showing sugestions   inline actionbar not start another activity